# PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (srv.sys) Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an HP proliant 380 gen9 server. The issue started with the server restarting it self on check the ilo logs i found out that we had smart battery failure so we replaced it. After turning it on again the system works for ~10 mins and then gives us blue screen with this error  "PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (srv.sys)" and then proceed to go to repair screen. We are using windows server 2012 r2.

Edit : Just install update https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2017/ms17-010 has solved my issue